# Javascript replace regexp \\n with \n, \\t with \t, \\r with \r and so on

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace

I'm having an HTML Input field where the user can enter a delimiter.

This delimiter can include `\n, \t, \r` and so on. When I append the delimiter to a string in javascript it is appended as \n instead of as a newline character.

While I can use `str.replace(/\\n/g, "\n")` and so on to replace one variation it does not work if I write a general catch-all regexp like `str.replace(/\\([a-z])/g, "\$1")` since this just replaces \n with \n again.

How do I have to rewrite the RegExp to replace all double backslashes in front of a character?

Comment: as I wrote in my post this works, I just want to have a generalized solution instead of right now chaining .replace(/\\n/g, "\n").replace(/\\t/g, "\t").replace(/\\r/g, "\r") and so on .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shortcut to replace literals with escaped sequences but you may be able to use this:

```js
const cmap = {'n': '\n', 't': '\t', 'r': '\r'}

var str = `value1\rvalue2\tvalue3\nvalue4`

str = str.replace(/\\([nrt])/g, m => {return cmap[m[1]]})

console.log(str)
```